# How to get a series of highest values out of equal portions of another pandas series python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am working with a series in python, What I want to achieve is to get the highest value out of every n values in the series.

**For example:**

if **n** is 3

**Series**: 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6, 9

**Expected Series**: 3, 6, 9

I have tried nlargest function in pandas but it returns largest values in descending order, But I need the values in order of the original series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various options. If the series is guaranteed to have a length of a multiple of n, you could drop down to numpy and do a `.reshape` followed by `.max` along an axis.

Otherwise, if the index is the default (0, 1, 2, ...), you can use `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 3
ser = pd.Series([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6, 9])
out = ser.groupby(ser.index // n).max()
```

out:

```
0    3
1    6
2    9
dtype: int64
```